# Most of something is plural or singular?

Tags: grammar, british-english

I am writing a literature review.
My question is which sentence is correct?

1. Most of the existing work focus on...
2. Most of the existing work focuses on ...
3. Most of the existing studies focus on ...

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the object after "**most**" is singular then the verb is singular too, else if the object after "**most**" is plural then the verb is plural:

- Most of his **ideas** *are* silly. *(ideas - plural, are - plural)*
- Most of his **money** *is* spent on PC games. *(money - singular (uncountable), is - singular)*

Your second and third sentences are correct. The first one is incorrect.

Comment: Trick question: "Most of the fish is/are edible"?

Comment: Does this boil down to whether the object is countable?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Both are possible. Most of the fish is - refers to one fish, it may be rather big in a certain context. Maybe a part of this fish isn't edible, like fins or head. Most of the fish are - refers to a number of fish.

Comment: But how. This looks incorrect. Like many people say "**a lot of books 'are' there**" but it is incorrect. The correct is "**a lot of books 'is' there**". Similarly, Most should be singular irrespective of the object being singular and plural.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Since when? **books** - plural, so **are**. That would work with uncountables only - **a lot of money is**.

Comment: No. "Be" verb is connected to "lot" not "book". So if it is "a lot" then "be" would be "is", and if it is "lots of books" then be would be "are".

Comment: @user54836 There are a lot of books on the table. The only exception I can remember is when we use There's instead of there is and there are. There's a lot of books on the table - which expands into There are although 's stands for is.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. *Most of the existing work focus on...*
> 2. *Most of the existing work focuses on ...*
> 3. *Most of the existing studies focus on ...*

Your ex.1 Is ungrammatical since it requires the 3rd person sing verb, “focuses”.

2 and 3. are okay – these are partitive constructions with the fused-determiner head “most”. The partitive oblique denotes a quantity and the matrix NP denotes a subquantity of that quantity.

The verb-form is determined by the matrix NP, in this case “most x”, where x may be singular or plural depending on the partitive oblique; in this singular  “work” and plural “studies”.